# What approach can be used to automate SQL views generation?

Tags: sql, automation, view

Let's say I have to create tons of different SQL views. **Having actual and target table DDLs, is it possible to programmatically automate view creation?**

Example: I have 2 table DDLs:

```
CREATE TABLE target_ddl (
  invoice_sum INTEGER,
  date date DATE
);

CREATE TABLE actual_ddl (
  amount INTEGER,
  year INTEGER,
  months INTEGER,
  day INTEGER
);
```

What I need to do is to make *actual_ddl* data match the *target_ddl* schema, so obvious answer is view creation:

```
CREATE VIEW actual_ddl_as_target_ddl AS
SELECT amount AS invoice_sum, 
DATE(CONCAT_WS('-', year, months, day)) AS date FROM actual_ddl;
```

I wrote this one manually. Thought I feel like it's possible to write java/python library which will "**create SQL views based on actual and target schema**". What algorithms/best practices should I look into to achieve it?

Comment: And how would your program know how to create the view?

Comment: No the "actual DDL" contains insufficient information to establish how the tables should be trabsformed and/or joined. The naming convention in this case makes some suggestion to a human reader as to how the tables can be joined in a natural way, but that relies on a conceptual understanding of the code which the computer does not have (even the unfamiliar human reader can only speculate as to whether a simple join between the dates would be a correct use of the tables).

Comment: To be more specific: I have a user input: which columns have to be mapped to which. E.g: (year, month, day) to date, OR (datetime) to date. So there is a limited number of possible input column formats. It is definitely possible but requires a lot of wotk. I'm concerned about the complexity of algorithms and whether there are some patterns I might use.